# Bengali not show properly in itext 5

Tags: android, itext, itext7

I am trying to create a pdf to the Bengali language.But not show in a proper format.

```
`Paragraph presAdviceVal = new Paragraph();
                    presAdviceVal.setIndentationLeft(10);
                    presAdviceVal.setFont(customBangla);
                    presAdviceVal.setSpacingAfter(40);
presAdviceVal.add(new Chunk(" \u00BB "+"\u0986\u09b2-\u09ac\u09bf\u09b0\u09c1\u09a8\u09c0\u09b9\u09be\u09b8\u09aa\u09be\u09a4\u09be\u09b2 \u09b2\u09bf\u09ae\u09bf\u099f\u09c7\u09a1"));
                    //presAdviceVal.setFont(customBangla);
                    cell.addElement(presAdviceVal);`


    banglaFont = BaseFont.createFont("/assets/fonts/vrinda.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
             customBangla = new Font(banglaFont, 10);
```

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain scripts such as Bengali, Hindi, Tamil, Devanagari, Punjabi, etc use advanced typography features.

These can typically not be rendered with `iText5`.
In `iText7` this can be achieved by using `pdfCalligraph`. An add-on that knows the advanced features of all of these scripts and automatically applies them based on the glyphs and characters being used.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joris, pdfCalligraph is free or paid?

Comment: pdfCalligraph is currently a paid add-on. If you have more questions about the cost and licensing, please contact a local sales rep. I can help you on technical questions, but not on licensing or pricing questions.